Prove that for every positive integer n, the equation P(P(... (P(x)) ...))=0 has at least one real solution
Let $P(x) = x ^ 2 + 2007x + 1$. Prove that for every positive integer n, the equation $P(P(... (P(x)) ...))=0$ has at least one real solution, where the composition is performed n times
I am new to polynomials, so I have no idea how to proceed. Only thing I know is that if degree of $P$ was odd, then we are done by Complex Root Theorem, but that's not the case. So any hint/solution would be appreciated.

Starting with $P(P(x))$, the polynomial seems almost nonnegative-valued. See https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=f%28f%28x%29%29+%3D+0%2C+where+f%28x%29+%3D+x%5E2+%2B+2007x+%2B+1 for $P(P(x))$ and see https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=f%28f%28f%28x%29%29%29+%3D+0%2C+where+f%28x%29+%3D+x%5E2+%2B+2007x+%2B+1 for $P(P(P(x))))$.

Im guessing this is going to be used

As you noted, $P_n(x)=P(P(\ldots P(x)\ldots))$ ($P$ applied $n$ times) is a polynomial with an even degree, so it will have positive function values with $|x|$ large enough. What you need is a negative (or zero) function value, which means (due to all polynomials being continuous) that the intermediate value theorem guarantees $P_n$ has a real root.
The idea (which is often usable when iterated functions are used) is to find a negative fixpoint of $P(x)$, that is a negative value $x_f$ such that $P(x_f)=x_f$. Because if we can find such an $x_f$, we know that $P_2(x_f)=P(P(x_f))=P(x_f)=x_f$ and this goes on for all $P_n(x),n\ge 1$. That would give us argument where each $P_n$ has a negative value.
Finding such a value is simply solving a quadratic equation
$$x^2+2007x+1 = x \iff x^2+2006x+1=0.$$
Using the solution formula for the quadratic equation leads to
$$x_{1,2}=-1003 \pm \sqrt{1003^2-1}$$
The value under the square root is non-negative, so both solutions are real. The solution using $"-"$ in the formula is obviously negative, the one using $"+"$ is as well, but one negative solution is enough.
That means $x_f=-1003 - \sqrt{1003^2-1}$ is a fixpoint of $P(x)$ and so, as explained above, a fixpoint of every $P_n(x)$. Since $x_f < 0$, we know that $P_n(x_f) = x_f < 0$ and since $\lim_{x\to+\infty}P_n(x) = +\infty$ there will be positive function values of $P_n(x)$ as well, so there must be a real root in between.

The minimal value of any quadratic polynomial is $m=c-\frac{b^2}{4a}$ while roots are of the form $\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$. Now if $b$ is large enough, $a$ close enough to $1$ and $c$ close enough to $0$, then this means that at least the right root (i.e. the one corresponding to "$+$") will be greater than the minimal value. You can verify it on your own that this is the case with your polynomial.
Next the minimum of $P$ (i.e. the argument $w$ such that $f(w)=m$) is given by $\frac{-b}{2a}$, which also falls into $[m,\infty)$ for sufficiently large $b$ and $a$ close enough to $1$. Which again is the case here. Which implies that $P([m,\infty))=[m,\infty)$.
What that means is that if $r_1$ is the right root of $P$, then $r_1\geq m$ and therefore there is $r_2\geq m$ such that $P(r_2)=r_1$. And there is $r_3\geq m$ such that $P(r_3)=r_2$, and there is $r_4\geq m$ such that $P(r_4)=r_3$, and so on... Of course $r_n$ is the root of $n$-th composition of $P$ with itself.
